# Create UObject with global lifetime

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I have a plain C++ class where I need to have property of type UObject.

```
class A {
private:
    UObject* SomeSpecialObject;
};
```

If I create such property with `NewObject` I will get dangling pointer when I load new level/map because of GC. I can use weak pointer and check if object is still alive but I need this object to have same lifetime as application.

How to create UObject with such global lifetime?

Comment: It depends on what the object is, you could inherit `UGameInstanceSubsystem` `/* auto instanced and initialized systems that share the lifetime of the game instance */`. There's also `UEngineSubsystem` which shares the lifetime of the module it's created in.

Comment: @George in my case it will be overkill so `AddToRoot()` did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's an Unreal Engine question.
Once your UObject is created, you can call its method "AddToRoot()". After that, it will never be deleted by the GC.

https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/CoreUObject/UObject/UObjectBaseUtility/AddToRoot/index.html

*Add an object to the root set. This prevents the object and all its descendants from being deleted during garbage collection.*